# UIImage not displaying in Table View

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uiimage

I am trying to display image in each row. I have a switch to decide where is which picture. I don't get any picture displayed though. Anybody experiencing same issue?

Here is the code:

```
    self.statIcon = (UIImage *)[cell viewWithTag:42];

    NSString *statusPath;
    switch ([[[self.logList objectAtIndex:position] objectForKey:@"STATE"] intValue]) {
        case 1:
            statusPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"log_acc" ofType:@"png"];
            break;
        case 2:
            statusPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"log_dec" ofType:@"png"];
            break;
        case 3:
            statusPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"log_rights" ofType:@"png"];
            break;
        default:
            statusPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"log_rights" ofType:@"png"];
            break;
    }
    UIImage *statImg = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:statusPath];
    self.statIcon = statImg;
```

From DEBUGGER:

```
(NSString *) $1 = 0x001218b0 /var/mobile/Applications/167CC386-A0EE-4E05-BADD-B0307A01D684/My App.app/log_acc.png

(UIImage *) $0 = 0x00132e20 <UIImage: 0x132e20>
```

Comment: What are the values of statusPath and statImg just before your last line?

Comment: So, you can add an assert(stating); right after you get it from the file system (to insure you got an image). But what you didn't show is where you are setting the image in the cell. You have to set the image in an image view in the cell each time the delegate is asked for the cell, regardless if you created a cell or are using a recycled one.

Comment: Got it! The thing was only to change UIImage to UIImageView! Thanks so much! Could you please make it an answer so I can accept it in order to wrap this thing up?

Comment: Yeah, UIImage isn't a view, so asking for it via `viewWithTag:` won't return a view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, thanks to [David H](https://stackoverflow.com/users/96716/david-h) I was able to find solution to my problem. The main issue was, that `self.statIcon` was `UIImage` instead of `UIImageView`. So all it took was change the type and at the end use function `setImage`!

Here is the code:

```
    self.statIcon = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:42];
    NSString *statusPath;
    switch ([[[self.logList objectAtIndex:position] objectForKey:@"STATE"] intValue]) {
        case 1:
            statusPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"log_acc" ofType:@"png"];
            break;
        case 2:
            statusPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"log_dec" ofType:@"png"];
            break;
        case 3:
            statusPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"log_rights" ofType:@"png"];
            break;
        default:
            statusPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"log_rights" ofType:@"png"];
            break;
    }
    UIImage *statImg = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:statusPath];
    [self.statIcon setImage:statImg];
```